# The style attribute for a static UITableViewCell is missing in story board editor

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I am trying to create a very simple UITableView with **static** cells from within the Story Board editor in Xcode.  I dragged a UITableViewController onto the story board, set the Content attribute on the Table View to "Static Cells".
I would like to set the style on the individual cells to Subtitle, as well as set the text that should appear in the cells.  However, when I open the attribute inspector for any of the UITableViewCells, the Style attribute is missing, and double-clicking on the cell doesn't allow me to edit the text for that cell.

*Note: I don't want to set this in code as based on a number of tutorials which I have watched, it should be possible to set this directly in the storyboard editor*

I am using Xcode 4.2 Build 4D151a.

Is this just a 'feature' of the version of Xcode I am using, or has anyone else had this problem and been able to fix it?

Comment: works for me. Xcode 4.3.2. If in doubt, update.

Comment: Worked for me in 4.2 - are you sure you've selected the cell, and not the section or the content of the cell? Have you set the number of cells in the section? Try selecting a cell from the document outline on the left of the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I upgraded to Xcode 4.3.2.